# Change project region location in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

We changed the region for our organization in Azure Devops from North Central US to West Europe. Some of the projects in the organization still has a location North Central US while most of the projects has been moved to West Europe. Is it possible to change the location(region) for a specific project?

Comment: This is not something that you can do yourself; you need to contact support for this one.

Comment: Yes, I will do that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think no. Team projects collection (or organization in Azure Devops Services) in TFS is a one big database. I think Azure Devops Services uses the same way. So it`s not possible to split a database between regions through user entities.

Comment: Well thats whats happened and that is not what I want. It might be so that the projects still in US was created before the organization unit was created. I guess the next question is if its possible to move the projects into the correct organization (Default collection)

Comment: that was planned for 2019 year: [make it possible to move a Team Project between Team Project Collections](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te)